# Increment duplicates in Pandas time axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, running-count

I have a `pd.DataFrame` which has duplicate time in its index.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

time_index = [
    datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 80000), datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 80000), datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 80000),
    datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 2), datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 3)
]
df_i_have = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], columns=['A'], index=time_index)
```

Notice that the first three rows have the exact same time.

My goal is to convert this data frame to one with unique time index. More specifically, I would like to add to each duplicated time on the dataframe index, one some small `timedelta` such that I end up with a dataframe like this one:

```
new_time_index = [
    datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 80000), datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 81000), datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 82000),
    datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 2), datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 3)
]
df_i_want = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], columns=['A'], index=new_time_index)
```

Can anyone please help with an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can groupby and cumcount and then add milliseconds:

```
t = df_i_have.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df_i_have.index += pd.to_timedelta(t,unit='ms')
```

---

```
print(df_i_have)

                         A
2017-01-01 00:04:01.080  1
2017-01-01 00:04:01.081  2
2017-01-01 00:04:01.082  3
2017-01-01 00:04:02.000  4
2017-01-01 00:04:03.000  5
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in theory possible for a duplicate to be produced as a result of an adjustment. As such, an adjustment can in theory need to be applied more than once in a loop. This looping is risked more when the increment is a microsecond rather than when it's a nanosecond.

```py
def deduplicate_index_timestamp(df: pd.DataFrame, /, *, unit: Optional[str] = None) -> list[int]:
    """Deduplicate the datetime index of the given dataframe in-place by incrementing duplicate values.

    Return a list containing the number of adjusted values in each iteration of the deduplication.

    If `unit` is not provided, it is the unit of the index.
    """
    # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77118638/
    if unit is None:
        unit = df.index.dtype.unit  # This is preferred over df.index.resolution, with the latter risking a lower resolution.

    assert df.index.is_monotonic_increasing
    num_adjusted = []
    while not df.index.is_unique:
        adjustment = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
        num_adjusted.append(sum(adjustment > 0))
        adjustment = pd.to_timedelta(adjustment, unit=unit)
        df.index += adjustment
    assert df.index.is_monotonic_increasing
    assert df.index.is_unique
    return num_adjusted
```

Note that [`SeriesGroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.cumcount.html) starts numbering at 0, not at 1.

For a list of units, see [`pd.to_timdelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html).